# Numpy Operation

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to figure out how to divide each value in numpy array with the total number of values. And
write the result to a new array. I tried a for loop but got all zeros in the new array.
Maybe array needs to be flattened. Any suggestions?
Thanks for your help.

```
tf = np.array([[1,0,2],[0,2,0]])

array([[1, 0, 2],
       [0, 2, 0]])
```

Here is the output I want

```
array([[0.333, 0.   , 0.667],
       [0.   , 0.667, 0.   ]])
```

Comment: You might want to name it something other than `tf` since that typically refers to `tensorflow`.

Comment: Were you trying to modify each element in-place?  Your array is integer dtype, but you want float values.  Didn't you read enough of the basic numpy docs to learn that you can do math on the **whole** array?  `tf/3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the array dimensions of `tf` using [`tf.shape`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html#numpy.ndarray.shape), the inner dimension is `tf.shape[1]`. So just divide by that:

```py
tf = np.array([[1,0,2],[0,2,0]])
tf = tf / tf.shape[1]
tf
```

Output:

```
array([[0.33333333, 0.        , 0.66666667],
       [0.        , 0.66666667, 0.        ]])
```